# word dialogue box opens

Tags: vba, ms-word, ord

This is my first post, I am not a programmer.

I built a Word macro (visual basic) that does a search and replace for many items (dates and numbers) within a **highlighted** block of text. Here's a single search and replace segment.  It works well, but after each segment a Y/N dialogue box (in this case Word 2003) appears asking if I want to search the remainder of the document--I DONT.

Query:  Is there anything I can add to macro that would respond "NO" (after each search and replace segment) as the macro runs so I don't have to select "no" after each of the 20 or so segments?

Typical segment:.

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting.
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting.
With Selection.Find.
    .Text = "2015".
    .Replacement.Text = "2016".
    .Forward = True.
    .Wrap = wdFindAsk.
    .Format = False.
    .MatchCase = False.
    .MatchWholeWord = False.
    .MatchWildcards = False.
    .MatchSoundsLike = False.
    .MatchAllWordForms = False.
End With.
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

...

THX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
.Wrap = wdFindAsk
```

tells Word that you want it to ask the user whether to keep searching. Changing that line to

```
.Wrap = wdFindStop
```

should fix your problem.

Comment: **This worked well.** I write several books that get updtaed each year. I've used macro since 2003 having to answer "No" thousands of times. Your suggestion will save much time. 63 changes were made to my macros; they should now all work as enhanced/modified. Thx Christina very much.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
*YOUR CODE HERE*
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Not sure about Word 2003 (!)

Comment: This did not work as intended. These statements, wherever I located them, did suppress the Y/N dialogue box, but the changes were not restricted to the highlighted area. Meatspace, thanks for your time.

Comment: BTW, I also tried using the statements once, as well as, before and after each segmnent (in various locations) to no avail.